# Changing the time on a wii console

Tags: nintendo-wii

Is it possible to change the time on a wii console as mine chages dates at about 7:30 in the evening

Answer (score 4):

1. Select the Wii button from the Wii menu
2. Select "Wii Settings"
3. Select "Calendar"
4. Select "Time"
5. Select the up or down arrows that adjust the hours and minutes

If you wish to adjust the Date, at step 4, select "Date" and perform step 5.

<sub>[(Source)](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1776/~/how-to-change-the-system-date-and-time)</sub>